# Using nested functions in C

Tags: c, function, gcc, nested, nested-function

I have written a function to be called by a main. In the function, I have a nested function.  I compile using:

```
gcc -o numericalIntegration numericalIntegration.c TrapezoidRule.c SimpsonsRule. GaussQuad.c -fnested-functions
```

Here is my TrapezoidRule:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define pi 3.1415927

//Note: This program was taken from the first practical and adjusted for sin instead of tan(x) and the limits of integration changed to o --> pi/3

double degtorad(double);

float TrapezoidRule(int args) {


int i, j; //Loop index, Counter, Array dimension
float area, rad, Sin[args], coeff; //Return value of the function, Result array, Area, Coefficient
 //TODO: Get table of sin as in Ex. 3

        j=0;

        for (i=0; i<=180; i=i+5) {
                rad = degtorad(i);
                Sin[j] = sin(rad);
                j=j+1;
                }

        area = Sin[0];
        for (i = 1; i < args - 1; i++) {
                area = area + 2.0*Sin[i];
                }
 //Calculating the area using the trapezoid rule and comparing to the real area 
        coeff = degtorad(2.5);
       // area = (area + Sin[dim - 1]) * coeff; 

 //Function to convert degrees to radians
    double degtorad(double arg) {
        return( (pi * arg)/180.0 );
    }

        area = (area + Sin[args - 1]) * coeff;

return area;

}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_degtorad", referenced from:
      _TrapezoidRule in ccdjbt6m.o
      _TrapezoidRule in ccdjbt6m.o

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I doing the nested function incorrectly?

Comment: Nested functions are a gcc extension -- and I don't see any reason for your `degtorad` function to be nested inside `TrapezoidRule`. Try moving the `degtorad` function out to file scope.

Comment: In the alternative, try moving the nested function to the top of the enclosing function.  If I remember correctly, nested functions need to have their *definition* visible at the point of the call; the file-scope forward declaration you have does not qualify as a forward declaration of the nested function.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Nested-Functions.html particularly the part at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the declaration of `degtorad()` before the definition of `TrapezoidRule()`.
2. Move the defintion of `degtorad()` to the beginning of `TrapezoidRule()`, or at least before the call to it.

---

If you want to declare a nested function first, and put its definition at the end of its containing function, you could do something like:

```
float TrapezoidRule(int args) {
    auto double degtorad(double);

    coeff = degtorad(2.5);

    double degtorad(double) {
        /* .... */
    }
}
```

See [6.4 Nested Functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) for further details.